# How to replace GE water dispenser tube

Tags: refrigerator, leaking

We moved this fridge ( *GE mod:GSS22JEPD BB* ) and had to remove the doors.

In the process of removing the freezer door, I believe we cracked the water tube. Now when connecting the fridge to a water line, we notice water leaking from the tube right by the door hinge.

I bought a new water line to replace this. Unfortunately, every tutorial I found does not show me how to get this dispenser out of the door and replace the tube.

I tried pulling on the nozzle, but seems quiet stuck.

Can someone please help.

[image]

[image: dispenser nozel]

UPDATE:
Unfortunately, I found out that I cannot replace this particular water tube, I would have to replace the entire door. Is there any way to somehow seal the portion of the tube by gluing a seal as a 'wrapper' of sorts instead of shelling out $hundreds for a door? Any creative suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure it is cracked, can you see the crack ? Is it close to the end of the hose, can it be cut out ?  Did you get the push to connect fitting FIRMLY seated ?

Comment: Well water is coming out from right under the door hinge where the tube comes out of, and where it was pinched when we took the door off. That's why I'm saying it was cracked. I've already replaced the fitting that it connects to under the fridge

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where the leak is in the tube but the trickle is pretty close to the door hinge which doesn't leave much room to cut and replace. I'm not sure which fitting you mean that should be "FIRMLY seated". Do you mean the white tube fitting at the bottom that connects the two water lines? If so, yes that was firmly connected when I tested.

Comment: @Alaska Man, if I do cut the line to replace it, how do I attach another piece to it?

Comment: In your first photo is white push to connect fitting on the end of the tube on the right, it has a drop of water on it. That is the fitting  i was talking about, the tube on the left should be connected to that fitting,( pushed into it very firmly to seat it ) if you do not no what i was talking about then does that mean you did not disconnect it ? How did it get disconnected ?  Have you called GE support ?  https://www.geappliances.com/appliance/GE-22-0-Cu-Ft-Side-By-Side-Refrigerator-with-Dispenser-GSS22JETBB

Comment: Thanks, @AlaskaMan. Yes, I had the line connected to the fitting. It was firm enough where it was not leaking from there. I've updated the picture in the description with where the water is coming from. The drop on the fitting is there because when I disconnected the line, it still had water in it which drained out, so a drop remained on the fitting. Is there a way to replace this line or if I cut it right under the door, a way to connect two pieces together?