# How to seal a refrigerator water line

Tags: leak, refrigerator, leaking

I have a GE GSS22JEPDBB model fridge. The water line that goes into freezer door and then to the dispenser is leaking water right at the bottom of the door. Not sure exactly where. I suspect this is the source of the leak because it was damaged during a move. Unfortunately, I found out that I cannot replace this particular water tube, I would have to replace the entire door.
Is there any way to somehow seal the portion of the tube by gluing a seal as a 'wrapper' of sorts instead of shelling out $hundreds for a door? Any creative suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace GE water dispenser tube](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/192661/how-to-replace-ge-water-dispenser-tube)

Comment: Hey Jimmy. No unfortunately it doesn't. If I do cut the tube, how do I go about attaching another piece to it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Please don't ask multiple questions on the same topic.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. In retrospect, I should have updated the original question, which I've done now. I guess I posted a new one to get get an answer quickly as there was no activity on that post for a few days.

Answer (score 1):

This is why you are not getting helpful answers:

> "the dispenser is leaking water right at the bottom of the door. **Not sure exactly where**"

Without an idea about the source, location, and nature of the leak it is impossible for anyone to tell you how to fix it. Most assuredly, any attempt will fail unless you pinpoint the leak source.